# Keras custom loss: how do I know to which patterns correponds to y_pred and y_true?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

In keras you can define a custom loss with arguments `(y_true, y_pred)`.
How do I know to which patterns are they correlated?
I mean, `y_true` is a tensor with `batchSize` elements. How can I relate those element to the original `X`?
I would like to know the correspondence between `y_true[0]` and the relative `X[i]`.

Comment: what is the bigger problem you want to solve ?

Comment: order of 1E5 input paterns (training)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check tips on how to questions which get answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you can help me you'll be mentioned on a paper I'm writing.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. For all the built in loss functions it is important that `y_true` exactly corresponds to `X`, i.e `y_true[i]` is the expected result for the input `X[i]` for all `i`. However, if you are writing your own loss function (maybe a very exotic one), you are of course free to implement it in whatever way you want. Whether that makes sense in the end is another story...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand either. I thought that y_true and y_pred were referred to the batch that the model is working on. And the batchSize is typically << training size.

Comment: Yes, for each call of the loss function `y_true` and `y_pred` are one batch. So, if you have 500 batches, your loss function will be called 500 times. Keras guarantees that each `y_true` batch belongs to the corresponding `X` batch, even if you pass `shuffle=True` to `model.fit()`.

Comment: For example: if the custom loss is considering the b-th batch, how do I know the starting index (i) of y_true (y_pred) in order to recover X[i]?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. So, your custom loss not only needs `y_true` and `y_pred`, but also the corresponding portion of `X`, is that right? Btw: when you are answering me you should add @sebrockm. Otherwise I won't get a notification.

Comment: @sebrockm: that's correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206058/discussion-between-filippo-portera-and-sebrockm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you would like to have is a loss function like this

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, X):
```

because you need the input for your loss calculation.
That's not directly possible in Keras, as far as I know.

One possible workaround could be to have a running index:

```
X = ...
Y = ...
batch_size = ...
i = 0
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    x = X[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
    loss = ...
    i += 1
    return loss
```

Make sure to reset `i` after each epoch. You can do this in a [LambdaCallback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#LambdaCallback) that you pass to `model.fit()`. Also make sure to pass `shuffle=False` to `model.fit()`.

Comment: do you want to be mentioned in my paper? (I still don't if it will be accepted somewhere....)

Comment: @FilippoPortera Thank you, I appreciate that. But that's not necessary

Comment: I'm trying to reference and increment a global variable (g_i) inside a keras custum loss function. The problem is that python 3.7 complaints saying: "UnboundLocalError: local variable g_i referenced before assignment". While the others global variables are behaving well. I add that I put an assignmnet g_i=0 after the loss function definition.
The variables are not declared global.
Another problem is that I can't understand if the variable is properly incremented inside the custom loss function, because I cannot print it.

Comment: @FilippoPortera So, I'm not sure how to respond... you answered your question yourself. Just put `g_i=0` before the loss function, or what am I missing? And why can't you print? You should be able to... either way, I strongly recommend a debugger in order to check for correct behavior of your variables.